# Linux + get the all information about the hardware from machine by tool or script

Tags: linux

My Linux version Linux version 2.6.18-164.2.1.el5PAE

Maybe some one have script (ksh,perl or bash etc)
that can get all info from Linux system and display it.

For example

```
   cards in the linux machine (type , manufacture , SN etc..)
   cpu
   memory
   disks
   devices ....
```

Comment: related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/2300

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use:

- `lspci` (list all PCI devices)
- `lsusb` (list USB devices)
- `lshw` (list hardware)
- `hwinfo` (Hardware identification system)
- `dmidecode` (tool for dumping a computer's DMI (some say SMBIOS))
- `lm-sensors` (read temperature/voltage/fan sensors)
- `smartmontools` (show S.M.A.R.T.)

Comment: You can add fdisk -l (disks), free -m (RAM).

Comment: what is it S.M.A.R.T?

Comment: From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.): "S.M.A.R.T. (Self-Monitoring, Analysis, and Reporting Technology; sometimes written as SMART) is a monitoring system for computer hard disk drives to detect and report on various indicators of reliability, in the hope of anticipating failures."

Comment: monitoring system for hard disk(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.#Known_ATA_S.M.A.R.T._attributes)

Answer (score 3):

I don't have this kind of script but:

- lspci (list of pci devices, package pciutils)
- lsusb (list of usb devices, package usbutils)
- cat /proc/cpuinfo (processor info)
- cat /proc/meminfo (memory info)
- fdisk -l, cat /proc/partitions (list of partitions)
- cat /proc/mdstat (raid status)
- hdparm -I /dev/sd* (detail information about disk)
- lm-sensors (voltage and temperature sensors on motherboard)
- hddtemp (temperature of disks)
- mpt-status (scsi monitoring)
- ...

Answer (score 1):

You can use a number of command-line tools for that, namely: `dmidecode`, `lspci` and `lsusb`.
`lsusb` lists your USB devices, `lspci` lists your PCI devices (including internal ones) and `dmidecode` lists information from SMBIOS table (it provides info about your memory banks, mainboard, BIOS, PCI bus cotrollers, fans, CPU, etc).

Answer (score 0):

`find /{proc,sys} -exec cat {} \; >> ~/capture.txt`

Answer (score 0):

The guys here did a good job, but I can add:

`dmesg | less` to view the kernel messages. It can tell you a lot about your hardware.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [Linux-Hardware.org](https://linux-hardware.org/)'s hw-probe utility: https://github.com/linuxhw/hw-probe

Use [this Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/linuxhw/hw-probe/) in order to probe your hardware without the need to install anything on your host except Docker.

The probe includes outputs of popular Linux diagnostics tools (like smartctl, memtester, etc.), hardware listers (hwinfo, dmidecode, biosdecode, etc.), and system logs (Xorg.log, dmesg, etc.).

Probe example: https://linux-hardware.org/?probe=0b29192f95

[image]

[image]

I'm the author of this project, feel free to ask any questions in the comments.